# What is this formula trying to prove?

Tags: excel-formula, normal-distribution

I have a large spreadsheet with a number of forumlas and they all make complete sense apart from one, which is listed below. Does anyone have any idea what this NORMALDIST calculation is trying to acheive or tell me? It has relevants to HE
=MAX(1,NORMDIST(3,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(0,N18,N18/4,TRUE) + 2*(NORMDIST(6,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(3,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 3*(NORMDIST(9,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(6,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 4*(NORMDIST(12,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(9,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 5*(NORMDIST(15,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(12,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 6*(NORMDIST(18,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(15,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 7*(NORMDIST(21,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(18,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 8*(NORMDIST(24,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(21,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 9*(NORMDIST(27,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(24,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 10*(NORMDIST(30,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(27,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 11*(NORMDIST(33,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(30,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 12*(NORMDIST(36,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(33,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 13*(NORMDIST(39,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(36,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 14*(NORMDIST(42,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(39,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 15*(NORMDIST(45,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(42,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 16*(NORMDIST(48,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(45,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 17*(NORMDIST(51,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(48,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 18*(NORMDIST(54,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(51,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 19*(NORMDIST(57,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(54,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 20*(NORMDIST(60,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(57,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 21*(NORMDIST(63,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(60,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 22*(NORMDIST(66,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(63,N18,N18/4,TRUE)) + 23*(NORMDIST(69,N18,N18/4,TRUE)-NORMDIST(66,N18,N18/4,TRUE)))

Strange question I know, but could not think of where else to ask!!!
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation has a series of terms of the form `N*[NORMDIST(3N,mu,sigma)-NORMDIST(3N-3,mu,sigma)]` where mu is the mean (`N18` in the equation), sigma is the standard deviation (`N18/4`), and with N going from 1 to 23. This *appears to be* an estimate involving the **average** of the normal distribution. It would be more rigorous for N to go from minus infinity to plus infinity and it's not clear why this formula truncated the interval to 1..23. Nevertheless, if the person who wrote the equation was calculating the average, then from the properties of the normal distribution you can derive a closed form solution as:

```
Total of all NORMDIST terms = mu/3 + 1/2
```

This will be accurate as long as mu (`N18`) is in the between 0 and 30. If you plug this into the equation you get

```
=MAX(1,N18/3+0.5)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks #xidgel that helps. No idea why it goes only to 23. But will check.  Might need to do some more research as to why they have done this. Pushing my boundaries of knowledge.  Maybe come back to you direct xidgel cheers

Comment: Also are you saying it should be 1 to 30 and not 1 to 23

Comment: @Processit Let me be more clear. If `N18` is in 0 to 30 the formula I provided gives a result that is pretty close to your original formula. If `N18` is outside that range the two formulas start to diverge.

Comment: @xidegel thank you for that and yes I have rerun the formula and it does keep it close in line with the other long winded version. However you are right it deviates when it gets to over 30 for example: 41 = New formula 14.167 old formula 14.089. However what I now need to brush up on is why you would want to do this

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs...](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/normdist-function-126db625-c53e-4591-9a22-c9ff422d6d58)

NORMDIST function
Excel for Office 365 Excel for Office 365 for Mac Excel 2019 Excel 2016 More...
Returns the normal distribution for the specified mean and standard deviation. This function has a very wide range of applications in statistics, including hypothesis testing.

Important: This function has been replaced with one or more new functions that may provide improved accuracy and whose names better reflect their usage. Although this function is still available for backward compatibility, you should consider using the new functions from now on, because this function may not be available in future versions of Excel.

For more information about the new function, see NORM.DIST function.

Comment: The parameters are constant apart from the value and then they are being summed and subtracted. I can't think of an appropriate use case but someone must had had one :)